# Computing the quantity $ \frac{{x}\cdot{y}}{{\|x\|\|y\|}}$ in terms of $a$ where $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(a,-2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Let $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(a,-2)$ be  two vectors $ℝ^2$, where $a$ is a real number. Then compute the quantity
> $$
> \frac{{x}\cdot{y}}{{\|x\|\|y\|}}$$
> in terms of $a$.

**My work so far:**

$$x\cdot y=1\cdot a+0\cdot(-2)=a$$

And so

$$\|x\|=\sqrt{{1^2}+{a^2}}=1+a$$

$$\|y\|=\sqrt{{0^2}+{(-2)^2}}=2$$

Thus

$$\cos(\theta)\frac{a}{\sqrt{{2a+2}}}$$
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2a+2}}$$

And I'm stuck here. Where did I go wrong to compute the quantity in terms of a? Would there be any better ways of tackling this?

Comment: Isn't $||x||=\sqrt{1^2+0^2}$ and $||y||=\sqrt{a^2+(-2)^2}$ so it's $\dfrac a{\sqrt{a^2+4}}$?

Comment: Also note that, in general, $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}\neq p+q$.

Comment: I think you confuse the $x$ as vector and $x$ as component of the vector.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for that! I figured it was due to a miscalculation on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation that $\;\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y=a\;$ was okay, but

$||\mathbf x||=||(1,0)||=\sqrt{1^2+0^2}=1,$ and $||\mathbf y||=||(a,-2)||=\sqrt{a^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{a^2+4},$

so  $\dfrac{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{||x||||y||}}
= \dfrac a{\sqrt{a^2+4}}.$

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you should be aware that

$\sqrt{1^2+a^2}$ does not generally equal $1+a$.  (To see that, try squaring them both.)

Comment: Thanks again. Your feedback is much appreciated and I can see where I went wrong.